# Erro npm e node Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Tive muitos problemas para instalar o npm e node no ubuntu, agora estou com o seguinte erro:

```
    npm : Depende: nodejs mas não será instalado

    mais um monte de dependências...

    E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.
```

Alguém conhece?

Comment: tb tenho esse erro ao executar:  /usr/local/bin/npm : Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique se você consegue corrigir os pacotes quebrados:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Se ele lhe der as opções possíveis para corrigir os pacotes, pode prosseguir. Pode ser que a instalação do pacote nodejs tenha falhado.

Se encontrar ainda um comportamento estranho, é recomendável você desinstalar o npm e reinstalá-lo já com o pacote nodejs também.

```
sudo apt-get remove npm nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm nodejs
```

Comment: Ao rodar o primeiro comando me retornou isso: Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 56 não atualizados.

Comment: Ao rodar os 2 ultimos deu isso: Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 nodejs : Conflita: npm
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.

Comment: Ao executar somente `sudo apt-get remove npm` ele é capaz de remover e deixar você executar o comando de instalação?

Comment: Funcionou ao executar os comandos e reuniciar a máquina, obrigada.

Answer (score 2):

A sequência de comandos acima não deu certo pra mim, pra resolver o problema segui os passos abaixo, caso ocorra com alguém.

Dependências desencontradas e pacotes quebrados que impediam de instalar um programa conseguir resolver
consegui resolver dando um:

```
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade

sudo aptitude update

sudo aptitude install pacote
```

ele tenta da uma solução alternativa quando encontra pacotes quebrados enquanto o apt-get não o fez!

Answer (score 1):

No momento em que eu escrevo, as versões oficiais dos repositórios são:

```
$ node -v
v8.10.0

$ npm -v
3.5.2
```

Elas conflituam com os pacotes "libcurl4-openssl-dev" e "libssl-dev".

**A única saída é instalar a última versão indo direto à fonte.**

Conforme https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

**Node.js v12.x:**

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Agora sim:

```
$ node -v
v12.8.0

$ npm -v
6.10.2
```

Se por acaso você desinstalou os pacotes lá em cima:

```
$ dpkg -s libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Então:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Tive esse problema com o Ubuntu 21, não conseguia atualizar o NodeJS nem o NPM, me dava erro de pipe quebrado, o APT não foi suficiente para resolver o problema, removi as libs com o comando:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* ; sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/* ; sudo apt-get -f install ; sudo apt-get clean ; sudo apt-get update
```

Logo Após usei a resposta do amigo João Martins, que resolveu o problema por definitivo.

```
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install nodejs
sudo aptitude install npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava com esse erro, e quase fiquei louco, utilizo o Ubuntu 16.04. Tentei tudo aí em cima, mas nada funcionou. O jeito que deu certo foi acessar o terminal como root, através do comando `su` e conforme a documentação oficial (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#deb), fazer os seguintes passos no terminal:

```
# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Entretanto, o comando npm -v só funciona logado como root, como usuário normal ele continua com o mesmo erro informando que o comando npm não existe, e caso tentar instalar pelo usuário comum o mesmo erro anterior continua. Acredito que o NPM não funciona para usuários comuns. Para corrigir isso tem a explicação desse link https://woliveiras.com.br/posts/corrigindo-permissoes-de-usuario-linux-npm/.

Acredito que depois de instalar o NodeJS como usuário comum e seguir as instruções do segundo link resolva também.